# SQL NOT LIKE returning all rows instead of dissimilarities

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, with 2 PKs. Table 1 has 478 records. Field 1 is a unique ID for that table only. Table 1 field 2 is a ID (shared with table 2) and 3rd field is a category field. IDs from field 2 can be repeated within a table, but I cannot have ID+category twice.

I have a 2nd table, that contains 757 records. It has a ID column and a category column (such as table1) and I want to know which records from table 1 are included on table 2. By the moment I am just checking which IDs are included in both tables (I want to clean up the database so I can use an `AND` query to obtain ID + category)

My SQL query does not return the desired result. When I do

`SELECT DISTINCT(table1.field1) FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.ID = table2.ID;`

I get all the results that do match, but, when I do the opposite

`SELECT table1.field1 FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.ID != table2.ID;`

SQL gives all the rows from table 1, when, the expected outcome would be

total rows from table 1 - IDs that do match with the ones at table 2

I've tried to invert the order in which the query is displayed as:

`SELECT table1.field1 FROM table1, table2 WHERE table2.ID != table1.ID;` 
But then a loop occurs and I get 36000+ results which is, of course, impossible (I imagine that checking a bigger record table against a smaller one makes the small one loop over and over, and seeing that I get the full table all the time, the loop is Xtimes478, hence the 36000+ results).

I have checked this matched/unmatched query using R (just for testing) and I got 170 matches (that I can obtain in SQL) and 308 "not coincident" results (170+308=478, so I imagine it makes sense even if I am using R instead of a proper relational database system)

How can I search for unmatched IDs in a query rather than checking for matched ones and substracting from total? How to get the 308 records that do not match?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `ON`.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`, and applies to the whole selected rows. Skip those extra parentheses to make the code clearer, i.e. simply `SELECT DISTINCT table1.field1 FROM ...`.

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields. And _rows_, not records.

Comment: @GordonLinoff appreciate the tip. Still I got the same result (478 records).
Any explanation on why the use of commas is not recommended? I always use them and never got a problem...

Comment: @jarlh Right! I am coming from R language, so I guess I'm uneducated on the proper terminology, thank you for the correction. On the parentheses it was because I had a `COUNT` that I deleted before posting and I kinda forgot about them.

Comment: Modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax is easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: "I never got a problem" - except now you got a problem

Comment: @Strawberry what? My problem does not come from commas. Their use is not recommended, not deprecated.

Comment: Cool - it's a bit odd that you use a phrase like "I'm fairly new" alongside a phrase like "I never got a problem".

Comment: @Strawberry I don't think this is the place for grammar but... I'm fairly new =not a lot of experience on X, never =haven't experienced something, where is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want values in table 1 that are not in table 2, then use `not exists` or something similar:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 where t2.id = t1.id);
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you. Didn't know about WHERE NOT EXISTS. I have to get my head around that structure as (as you can tell) I'm fairly new to SQL.